# spring websocket no spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket

I used spring websocket by stomp and spring message.
I don't like using spring security.
When I use:

```
SimpMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSendToUser(username,"");
```

I must :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()  // Refactor login form
            // See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11496
            .headers().addHeaderWriter(
                new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                        XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN)).and()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutUrl("/logout.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("lihui").password("1234").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("paulson").password("bond").roles("ADMIN","USER");
    }
}
```

So, what can I do? Please help.

Comment: What is it you don't like about this? I don't see the problem with this? You use Spring Security so you have to configure it. Also using WebSockets and sending to a user isn't bound to Spring Security (afaik it uses the principal) so again not sure what the issue here is (your question is not described clearly enough for that).

Comment: I want to useing spring websocket and stomp without spring security.

Answer (score 0):

```html
//when i not useing spring security.i can used
simpMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSendTo(usename,"queue/"+usename+"/greating",object);
//and client like this:
stompClient.subscribe('/queue/'++usename+'greetings', function (greeting) {
      showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
```